How can I setup an rPi both as Pi-Hole and access point?
I have configured a Raspberry Pi 3 as Pi-Hole and this works great. However, I want to use that same rPi as a wireless access point using hostapd. I have setup everything that my mobile devices find the SSID, get connected and get an IP address, including DNS and router.
However, still I cannot get to the internet, or even my internal net. I followed this guide, skipping the steps about the DHCP server (as PiHole handles that).
This is my /etc/hostapd.conf file:
country_code=NL
interface=wlan0
ssid=SSID
channel=9
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=PASSPHRASE
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

I enabled packet forwarding:
pi@pihole2:~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

and my iptables rules should also be fine:
pi@pihole2:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere  

I have configured both eth0 and wlan0 with a fixed IP. When wlan0 does not have a fixed IP, the mobile device does not get an IP address.
How can I get the routing correct when using an rPi both as PiHole and WiFi access point?

When wlan0 does not have a fixed IP" -- This is a bit confusing, if wlan0 is supposed to be the AP.  If it does not have a fixed address, where are you expecting it to get an address from?  The clients will still be able to connect to the SSID, but after that to what address should they send IP traffic if the AP has "no fixed IP" address?  There are two layers there that must both be working, the wifi SSID layer and the internet protocol (IP) layer on top of that, if the second one is misconfigured the first is useless.
